# Multiple products on one products page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I've decided that I will use Magento to build my eCommerce store but there is just one HUGE problem. My store will sell full outfits. You can either buy the basic top or bottom, you will also have the choice of accessories. Is it possible to add multiple products on one product page?? Will I need a custom template?? I'm worried that my idea will not be possible please help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing are "related products".  Products that go together or are somehow directly related to the one being viewed.  This would show the product being viewed (say a shirt) then toward the bottom of the page show a selection of products (can be chosen by you) related to this one.

Another option is bundling or grouping your products.  Bundles allow the customer to pick and choose individual elements to buy; whereas, grouped products are purchased as one set.  A grouped product might be a tuxedo and a bundle product would be a suit with the option to purchase a bow tie or vest or cummerbund.  Groups provide a more rigid setup for your products and bundles can give flexibility to the customer.

**EDIT**. Forgot to mention that all I specified above is available out of the box with Magento.  The only thing you may need adjusting is how related products are displayed.  I would play with it in your testing or development environment first to see how each one acts.  Generally speaking there should be little to no customization to achieve what you are asking for.

Comment: A stylist puts together a full outfit including accessories which are your choice to add to the purchase. So i am assuming I would need a custom template because I need all the products on one page where you can add the accessories to the order on that page. But I am confused when I am adding new products I am only allowed to add one product but the page has to have a feature where the buyer can add the accessories. Will the template solve this? Will I have to hire somebody to edit Magento for me to add this feature?    Thanks for your time brett